# Why does a left outer join query gives different results compared to a sub query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, db2

I run the following query against DB2 linux

```
select * from schemaname.A t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN schemaname.B t2 on t1.SSN = t2.mem_ssn
where t2.mem_ssn = t1.ssn
and t2.ind= 'Y'
and t1.ind = 'Y'
and t1.yyyy = '2018'
and t2.yyyy = '2018'
and t1.plan = '1340'
```

This gives 143 records.

Where as the following query returns 141 records

```
select * from schemaname.A where ind = 'Y' and yyyy = '2018' and plan = '1340' and ssn in
(select mem_ssn from schemaname.B where yyyy = '2018' and ind = 'Y')
```

Why is that difference?

Answer (score 3):

Your `where` conditions turn the `left join` into an `inner join`.  Hence, some rows are being filtered out from `schemaname.A` because there are no matches `schemaname.B`.

Put *all* conditions on the second table in the `on` clause:

```
select *
from schemaname.A t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     schemaname.B t2
     on t1.SSN = t2.mem_ssn and
        t2.mem_ssn = t1.ssn and
        t2.ind = 'Y' and
        t2.yyyy = '2018'
where t1.ind = 'Y' and
      t1.yyyy = '2018'
      t1.plan = '1340';
```

Conditions on the first table belong in the `where` clause.  Note:  I assume that all the constant values are strings, even those that look like numbers.  If they are really numbers, you should drop the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The first select really works like an inner join, as there are non-null values in where condition for t2.
But still, the difference comes from mem_ssn not being the primary key in t2.

E.g. if a particular value of mem_ssn is three times in t2, the first select gives all three rows, but the second with the subselect gives this value only once (if it is only once in t1).